# Am I using the StanfordParser wrapper for ruby properly? It's returning incorrect results

Tags: ruby, stanford-nlp

I've installed the latest version of the stanfordparser and the ruby wrapper library for it. When trying to test it with a simple example from the website:

vi test.rb:

```
require "stanfordparser"

preproc =
StanfordParser::DocumentPreprocessor.new
puts
preproc.getSentencesFromString("This
is a sentence.  So is this.")
```

ruby -rubygems test.rb

```
This
is
a
sentence
.
So
is
this
.
```

This is a sanity check really - am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the parser or wrapper?

Comment: yep, throw that down as an answer. The preproc returns nested arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be confused about how `puts` is formatting the output. Try this:

```
x = preproc.getSentencesFromString("This is a sentence. So is this.")
puts x.inspect
```

to make sure that you're getting what you're supposed to be getting.